Is there something off with the spam bot?
SO Question: Nasha Mukti Kendra in Chandigarh
I remember there being a bot in place to remove such questions (there was an entire chatroom dedicated to this).
How did the spam bot not capture this?

It is a sample set of one, by the way. It becomes valid to say things like "is there something off with the spam bot" if you have a dozen cases. We're not living in the 22nd century just yet where I assume technology will not be actually held together by complicated scripts that have to be monitored by human beings.

Disclosure: This isn't an official statement on behalf of the Charcoal project - it's my thoughts. That said, I am affiliated with Charcoal.
I assume you're referring to the SmokeDetector bot (a.k.a. SD) and the Charcoal HQ room (warning: room can contain NSFW content). That room is sometimes called CHQ.
While SD attempts to catch spam, it isn't perfect and can't catch everything.
However, you're somewhat incorrect. The post you're referring to was actually reported in Charcoal HQ after being caught by SmokeDetector.
That said (details here), it wasn't automatically flagged by SmokeDetector. Charcoal can't be perfect, and it's generally better to err on the side of caution when raising spam flags, especially automated ones. We really don't want to be wrong when spam flagging content.
While (many) human volunteers monitor SmokeDetector reports, the time of that specific report was less active, both in terms of spam and people activity. This can be seen in the graphs here:

A closely related graph depicts a higher-than-average time to deletion at that time:

There's also a bar chart of SmokeDetector's user activity over a day on its chat profile.

If you see a post that wasn't reported, you can mention it in Charcoal HQ and someone can report it to SmokeDetector. Just because a post is caught/reported doesn't automatically mean SmokeDetector will flag it, and that's a good thing and is by design.
